# Adding data between 2 textfields in a label tag without changing their positions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to append data in a label tag when i click on a button. The label tag lies between 2 textfields. I have left & right floated them both leaving space of the label tag to load data. The **problem** is that once the data is appended the textfield to the right moves to the next line. How do i avoid this and load data keeping the position of the textfields intact ? I Know this is **kid stuff** :(

Heres a part of the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftnav"><input type="text" id="num1"></div>
    <label id="Opr"></label>
    <div id="rightnav"><input type="text" id="num2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container
{
width: 100%;
}
#leftnav
{
float: left;
margin: auto auto auto 35%;
}
#rightnav
{
float: right;
margin: auto 35% auto auto;
}
```

Comment: the way u explained....sure looks like a rocket science thing....mind showing your code so we can help better??

Comment: It's already on the next line [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6KMBt/)

Comment: My bad. Don't consider the <br/> tag [now deleted]

Comment: If you want to keep the right text field in place, swap the order of  the label and the right nav. Try leftnav, then rightnav, then Opr

Comment: I want to keep the order same ! Possible ?

Comment: Changing 35% to 35px works for me [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6KMBt/7/)

Comment: **Solved :** Was stupid. Simply made 3 divs with all 3 of them having fixed properties ! Thus label data loading on a predefined area.

Answer (score 0):

Your container id and css container id are spelled wrong. You have a break after your label which is going to make your input box after go on the line below. You also should make your container a fixed width if you don't want anything in that div to move when the window is resized or any information inside the label is long enough to push the second input box down.

If you don't want to get rid of your right nav div, then fix your margins - the percentages are making them freely move:

```
#container { width: 900px; margin: auto auto; } 
#leftnav { float: left;  margin:auto auto auto 35px; } 
#rightnav { float: right; margin:auto 35px auto auto; }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zw23/3/)

Comment: Nope still aint working. Tried with one div as well.

Comment: Hmm..You might have to play with it using developer tools through your browser. Some browsers allow you to take off attributes that might be causing problems that I can't see with the code provided.

If you see something that might be affecting it and still need help, feel free to drop a line.